# Create a file on Android Internal Storage?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a text file in android's internal storage and browse through connecting it to a PC via usb. Now, I used the following code which worked fine for old devices with SD cards.

```
public void writeToFile(String stringToBeWritten)
{    
 final File path =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                (
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Target Folder/"
                );

if(!path.exists())
{
    path.mkdirs();
}

final File file = new File(path, "MyFile.txt");

try
{
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    myOutWriter.append(stringToBeWritten);
    System.out.println("Written Successfully");
    myOutWriter.close();

    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
}
```

I've been surfing for a solution a while and tried a lot of thing to get my job done. All the solutions out there, to store the file internally but unable to browse.

Any ideas how to write my files on internal phone storage? I'd highly appreciate any help/suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: can you please tell your mobile version and do you sdcard in your device

Comment: I'm using Oneplus One, have no sdcard. @jiteshmohite

Comment: OnePlus one api version ?

Comment: Its running on Nougat 7.1 (API level 25)

Comment: have  you handle run time permission for storage ? if not then you have to do.also you are not having sd card so you have to read about how to store file in internal storage. if you are not able to do these please let m know i will post the answer for you

Comment: Yes, I tried handling run time permission as I'm above api 23. I failed in many ways trying to do that, It would be great if you could post the answer. Thanks man.

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. Look at the function name. That is external storage. Not internal. And it has nothing to do with s SD card. So unclear where you are after.

Comment: `path.mkdirs();`. Check the return value as it might fail to create the directory in which case it returns false. If so display a toast to the user telling so and return. Do not continue with the code then as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.